# No such file or directory: 'google_news_vectors.bin'

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

> I am trying to load the google_news_vecotors.bin file but it gives an
> error. Below is my code it is written in the nlp_gen2.py file

```
import gensim
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('google_news_vectors.bin', binary=True)
```

**the error I get is:**

```
FileNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last) in 1 import gensim
----> 2 model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('google_news_vectors.bin',
binary=True)

C:\Anaconda3\envs\DataScience\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\keyedvectors.py
in load_word2vec_format(cls, fname, fvocab, binary, encoding,
unicode_errors, limit, datatype) 1547 return _load_word2vec_format(
1548 cls, fname, fvocab=fvocab, binary=binary, encoding=encoding,
unicode_errors=unicode_errors, -> 1549 limit=limit, datatype=datatype)
1550 1551 @classmethod

C:\Anaconda3\envs\DataScience\lib\site-packages\gensim\models\utils_any2vec.py
in _load_word2vec_format(cls, fname, fvocab, binary, encoding,
unicode_errors, limit, datatype, binary_chunk_size) 273 274
logger.info("loading projection weights from %s", fname) --> 275 with
utils.open(fname, 'rb') as fin: 276 header =
utils.to_unicode(fin.readline(), encoding=encoding) 277 vocab_size,
vector_size = (int(x) for x in header.split()) # throws for invalid
file format

C:\Anaconda3\envs\DataScience\lib\site-packages\smart_open\smart_open_lib.py
in open(uri, mode, buffering, encoding, errors, newline, closefd,
opener, ignore_ext, transport_params) 185 encoding=encoding, 186
errors=errors, --> 187 newline=newline, 188 ) 189 if fobj is not None:

C:\Anaconda3\envs\DataScience\lib\site-packages\smart_open\smart_open_lib.py
in _shortcut_open(uri, mode, ignore_ext, buffering, encoding, errors,
newline) 285 open_kwargs['errors'] = errors 286 --> 287 return
_builtin_open(local_path, mode, buffering=buffering, **open_kwargs) 288 289

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
'google_news_vectors.bin'
```

**my file structure is like below:**
[image]

[image]

how can I solve this?

Comment: I think your program is looking for a file called `google_news_vectors.bin`, which it doesn't find.

Comment: file is located at the same folder

Comment: The way you show your file structure is not ideal. Please [enable display of file extensions](https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/). Alternatively, open a command line in your directory and use the `dir` command to print the file list.

Answer (score 1):

The file name is "GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin", but as you can see, the file is corrupted. Download and unpack the rar again.

Comment: The new file is not corrupted and you typed the name correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not show clearly how your files are named, since your Explorer does not show file extensions.
See [this guide](https://www.howtogeek.com/205086/beginner-how-to-make-windows-show-file-extensions/) to turn them on.

For some reason you have a *folder* named `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin`. This should not be the case.

#### Option A - with manual unzipping

- Download `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz`. It should be exactly 1647046227 bytes, and its MD5 is `1c892c4707a8a1a508b01a01735c0339`.
  Confirm the file size by inspecting the file properties.
- Uncompress the file. It seems that you have WinRAR installed, and it should be able to perform the gunzip operation.
- You should now have a file `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin` at 3644258522 bytes, and its MD5 is `023bfd73698638bdad5f84df53404c8b`.
- Now, the following code should work:

  ```
  import gensim
  filename = 'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin'
  model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(filename, binary=True)
  ```

#### Option B - let gensim do the unzipping

- Download `GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz`. It should be exactly 1647046227 bytes, and its MD5 is `1c892c4707a8a1a508b01a01735c0339`.
  Confirm the file size by inspecting the file properties.
- Now, the following code should work:

  ```
  import gensim
  filename = 'GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz'
  model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(filename, binary=True)
  ```

---

<sub>This answer is based on this [Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aLNhDu1qtQnNIvN5Hhl0UhNBBe84N9S4?usp=sharing).</sub>